# Possible to reconstruct sparsebundle from bands folder only?

Tags: encryption, sparsebundle

I have an encrypted sparsebundle from mid-2013. I am aware of the encryption type (AES-256) and the passphrase used to create the sparsebundle.

Unfortunately, dropbox has somehow deleted all but the `bands` folder of this sparsebundle. Is it theoretically possible to recover the data from this sparsebundle without the `Info.plist` and `token` files? I have bands `0` and `1`.

Comment: Why not just create a new backup? Even if it were theoretically possible (I doubt it), would you trust it? It's a backup of your files, I wouldn't risk it.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on this - no, it is conclusively not possible to repair an encrypted sparsebundle without the `token` file. The `token` file contains the initialization details and salt for the encryption algorithm, which is just as essential as the passphrase for decrypting the data.